# Does dictionary's clear() method delete all the item related objects from memory?

Tags: python, memory, dictionary

If a dictionary contains mutable objects or objects of custom classes (say a queryset, or a even a  DateTime), then will calling `clear()` on the dictionary delete these objects from memory?
Does it behave differently than looping through the dict and `del`eting them?

eg.
consider

```
class MyClass(object):
    '''Test Class.'''

my_obj_1 = MyClass()
my_obj_2 = MyClass()

my_dict = { 'foo' : my_obj_1, 'bar' : my_obj_2 }
```

then is

```
my_dict.clear()
```

same as

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    del my_dict[key]
```

?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[Python documentation on dicts](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict) states that `del d[key]` removes `d[key]` from the dictionary while `d.clear()` removes every key, so basically their behavior is the same.

On the memory issue, in Python when you "delete" you are basically removing a reference to an object. When an object is not referenced by any variable nor other object or becomes unreachable, it becomes **garbage** and can be removed from memory. Python has a garbage collector that *from time to time* it does this job of checking which objects are garbage and releases the memory allocated for them.
If the object you are deleting from the dictionary is referenced by other variable then it is still reachable, thus it is not garbage so it won't be deleted. I leave you here some links if you are interested in reading about garbage collection in general and python's garbage collection in particular.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)
- http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection
- http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/gc/
- http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html

Answer (score 19):

There is in fact a very small difference between the two. `clear()` will free the memory of the hashset used in the dict, while removing the key will not.

```
a = dict.fromkeys(range(1000))

In [10]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[10]: 49432

In [11]: a.clear()

In [12]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[12]: 280

In [13]: a = dict.fromkeys(range(1000))

In [14]: for i in range(1000):
   ....:     del a[i]
   ....:     

In [15]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[15]: 49432
```

Comment: yes! I found the same thing, and it's very important, when you deal with a really big dict. I'd never use a `for` loop to delete all keys, since it just doesn't release the memory back and therefore has no sense

Answer (score 5):

> Does it behave differently than looping through the dict and `del`eting them?

It's worth noting here that any custom class implementing the `MutableMapping` abstract base class gets `clear()` as a "free" mixin method.

The only methods you need to override in order to instantiate a `MutableMapping` subclass are:

```
__getitem__, __setitem__, __delitem__, __iter__, __len__
```

Since you can store the data in your mapping class any way you like, the only way `clear()` can figure out how to actually clear your data is by using one or more of those five methods. Now, you might have a guess as to which methods `clear()` is using, but why guess when we can experiment?

```
import collections

class MyMap(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, mydict):
        self._top_secret_data = mydict

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print 'getitem'
        return self._top_secret_data[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise Exception('where did you want that?')

    def __len__(self):
        raise Exception('a gentleman never tells')

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        print '[shredding intensifies]'
        del self._top_secret_data[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        def keygen():
            for key in self._top_secret_data:
                print 'faster! faster!'
                yield key
        return iter(keygen())
```

Using the class defined above, it's easy to see how `clear()` is implemented:

```
>>> m = MyMap({1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'})
>>> m.clear()
faster! faster!
getitem
[shredding intensifies]
faster! faster!
getitem
[shredding intensifies]
faster! faster!
getitem
[shredding intensifies]
>>>
```

In other words, the `clear()` mixin method is basically implemented as `for key in self: del self[key]`.

Now, a disclaimer: Built-in types such as `dict` are implemented in C, so the `dict.clear` method may not be literally identical to `for key in mydict: del mydict[key]`. I would expect some optimization behind the scenes, perhaps a completely different strategy - but hopefully this example gives you some idea as to how you might *expect* a `clear()` method to work in Python.

Answer (score 4):

It is the same as calling `del d['foo']` - it just deletes the entries, but it does not affect the keys or values themselves.

Of course, they may then become garbage collectible if there are no other references to them.

Comment: In other words, if or the keys or the values are shared (assigned to another variable), their objects will not be deleted nor by `d.clear()`, nor by `del d[key]`.  A dictionary stores references to both keys and values.  The *references are deleted* by the operations.

Comment: Yep, so the key I was missing here is delete operation only deletes the reference, memory clearance is handled by garbage collector

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the two `MyClass` objects are shared. They will still be accessible via the `my_obj_1` and `my_obj_2`.

Answer (score 1):

the del command delete the reference of the particular item in the list, the clear command clear all the key value pairs in a go so the functionality is same they both dereference and rest task of removing it from memory is done by the garbage collector

Answer (score 1):

Have you even tried running the code? The following code with Python 3.7 throws exception! **"RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration"**:

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    del my_dict[key]
```

All previous answers are good. I just wanted to add couple more points about the differences of del and clear:

1. **my_dict.clear();** removes all the items in the dictionary and makes it equivalent to empty dictionary. Note: you still can add items to it if you want!
2. **del my_dict;** makes the object of my_dict to be deleted and garbage collection eligible (my_dict is not usable anymore)! So, if you try to add/access any item then you will get an exceptions.
3. Also, you have declared two variables my_obj_1 and my_obj_2; Even if you delete/clear my_dict, those two variables are holding references to MyClass objects and won't be going away until my_obj_1 and my_obj_2 are out of scope; so, if MyClass objects hold memory (say list or something) then if your intention is to release the memory by deleting/clearing my_dict, it is not happening!

   class MyClass(object):
       '''Test Class.'''

   my_obj_1 = MyClass()
   my_obj_2 = MyClass()

Comment: The question never says it's in python 3, because it is in python 2. Please check the date of the question, python 3.7 never existed back then, so it's not so wise to run that code with it.