# Removing items in a wierd type of list

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist

I am having trouble deleting everything in side of a list essentially clearing everything out of it such as this type of this.

```
{'p': [4, 1], 'o': [3, 5]}
```

I tried doing this `del {:}` but it doesn't work.
I also want to delete this type of this `del house[:]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion` but it comes up with that error.

Thanks for any help

Edit:

This is the code for a list

```
while Flag:
    try:
        h = str(input("Eneter House names [Type XXX to stop]: "))
        if h == 'XXX' or h == 'xxx':
            Flag = False
        else:
            house.append(h)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a word, Thanks")
print()
```

I want to be able to clear everything inside the list as well. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, you want to have empty lists as values for your dictionary? What do you want to delete exactly? You should post how the expected output should look like.

Comment: I want to delete this {'p': [4, 1], 'o': [3, 5]} in this dictionary list

Comment: You want to delete the entire dictionary not just the keys and values?

Comment: Sorry just the keys and values inside of the dictionary

Comment: Then you can use the `.clear()` method as @rikkigibson suggested.

Comment: @JoeR I updated the answer could you help me clear everything in this list?

Comment: so `house` is a list then? then what is this:`{'p': [4, 1], 'o': [3, 5]}` I am sorry, but it's a little confusing...

Comment: Sorry Joe house is a list the '{'p': [4, 1], 'o': [3, 5]}' is a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question, it seems a little unclear.

If you want to clear a dictionary you can do this:

```
>>> house = {'p': [4, 1], 'o': [3, 5]}
>>> house.clear()
>>> house
{}
>>>
```

If you want to clear a list you can do this:

```
>>> house = [1, 2, 3]
>>> house[:] = []
>>> house
[]
>>>
```

Or, this:

```
>>> house = [1, 2, 3]
>>> del house[:]
>>> house
[]
>>>
```

Comment: I am glad I could help!

Comment: One question on clear list, ut came up with this error TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: In my answer I presented general ways to delete lists and dictionaries. These methods work, so the error is probably cased by something else in your code. From what I see in your post, I can't tell what causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are lists. If you don't care about preserving the keys you can just overwrite your dictionary with an empty one.

```
myDictionary = {}
```

If you need to modify the same dictionary object so that everybody with a reference to it gets a clear dictionary, you can use the [`.clear()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446839/does-dictionarys-clear-method-delete-all-the-item-related-objects-from-memory) method on it.

Comment: How would I do that in this case?